# Vue 3 ref is not updating into component on template

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue3-carousel

I'm using [vue3-carousel](https://github.com/ismail9k/vue3-carousel) package for displaying `images/videos` on my project. I have faced with unexpected problem as for me. I don't know why `ref` is not updating on my template. I have this logic in `vue` component as shown bellow.

Template:

```
<carousel v-if="presentedImages.length" :items-to-show="2" :snapAlign="'start'" :breakpoints="breakpoints" :wrap-around="true">
    <slide class="slide" v-for="image in presentedImages" :key="image.id">
        <img v-if="image.attachment_url" class="videoFile" :src="image.attachment_url" />
        <div  @click="deleteImage(image.id)" class="fa-stack remove-button cross-btn">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </div>
    </slide>
    <template #addons>
        <navigation />
    </template>
</carousel>
```

Script:

```
const presentedImages = ref(props.images);
const deleteImage = (id) => {
    removeAttachment(id).then(res => {
        presentedImages.value = presentedImages.value.filter(img => {
            return img.id !== id;
        });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Can you please answer me why data is not updated in carousel component when I delete a image? FYI: Ref is updating in script.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at my example bellow...

This is not how you work with props. By doing `const presentedImages = ref(props.images);` you are creating new `ref` with the current value of `prop.images`. This means parent and child component are working with the same array instance...at first

So if you use only `+` buttons in my example, all is fine...

**But** once either parent (use `reset` button) or a child (`-` buttons) replace the value of their own `ref` by different array, the whole example brokes...

Correct way of creating `ref` in child that captures reactive value of prop is following:

```js
import { toRefs } from 'vue'

const { images: presentedImages } = toRefs(props);
```

This ref will change anytime parent changes the data pushed to prop **in any way**. BUT this ref is also **read only**. Because props are and always been [one way only](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#one-way-data-flow).

There are 2 solutions to this problem:

1. Never replace the value of prop/child ref with new array and only modify array in place (using `splice` instead of `filter`). This is possible but considered "dirty". Because it is really easy to broke the component by updating the ref. It is like a landmine waiting for a careless programmer...
2. Use the "correct" way above and embrace the principle of Vue - props are read only. Only component which owns the data should modify it. So your component should only fire an event and parent component should remove the image from the array...

```js
const generateItems = () => [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'item 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'item 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'item 3'
  },
]
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const items = Vue.ref(generateItems())

    let index = 100
    const addItem = () => {
      items.value.push({
        id: index,
        name: `item ${index}`
      })
      index++
    }
    const reset = () => {
      items.value = generateItems()
    }

    return {
      items,
      addItem,
      reset
    }
  },
  template: `
    Parent ({{ items.length}} items): {{ items }}
    <br>
    <button @click="addItem">+</button>
    <button @click="reset">reset</button>
    <hr>
    <child :items="items" />
  `,
})

app.component('child', {
  props: ["items"],
  setup(props) {
    const myItems = Vue.ref(props.items)

    /*
      This is better byt the ref is read only!
    */
    // const { items: myItems } = Vue.toRefs(props)

    let index = 4
    const addItem = () => {
      myItems.value.push({
        id: index,
        name: `item ${index}`
      })
      index++
    }

    const removeItem = (id) => {
      myItems.value = myItems.value.filter(img => {
        return img.id !== id;
      });
    }

    return {
      myItems,
      addItem,
      removeItem
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div> Child </div>
  <button @click="addItem">+</button>
  <hr>
  <div v-for="item in myItems" :key="item.id"> {{ item.name }} <button @click="removeItem(item.id)">-</button> </div>
  `,
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.7/vue.global.js" integrity="sha512-+i5dAv2T8IUOP7oRl2iqlAErpjtBOkNtREnW/Te+4VgQ52h4tAY5biFFQJmF03jVDWU4R7l47BwV8H6qQ+/MfA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your minds! I've tried different ways. But seems like the library cashed carousel items values. I can update items in my component, but it's not updated in carousel components.

Comment: I'm using this construction `const { images: presentedImages } = toRefs(props);` now. But when I changed a value for presentedImages I have this error in developer tools.
** Set operation on key "images" failed: target is readonly.**
I understand that props and refs is immutable. But I set value for presentedImages...
`presentedImages.value = presentedImages.value.filter(img => { return img.id !== id; }); `

Comment: This is expected. Read my answer again. You **can not** change parent component's prop value. Use events and remove the image in the parent...

Comment: It's the library issue. I tried different ways. It's working when you add/remove div, There is a problem if you are operating with the library components